# A single word for emotional connection

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word to explain how something happening to someone nearby can affect you?  Usually happens with emotions.  Similar to if someone is hit, you have sympathy pains, but not quite the same.

For example, if someone is nervous you also become nervous for no reason.

Comment: Erm...maybe _empathy_?

Answer (score 3):

I believe the word you are looking for is empathize, to experience [empathy](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/empathy?s=t):

> the psychological identification with or vicarious experiencing of the
>   feelings, thoughts, or attitudes of another.

Comment: I've edited your post to include the reference. Without references, posts often get closed. To add a reference, you put the word you want to highlight in square brackets and add the link from the browser in round brackets, in your example: [empathy](link address copy pasted here).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you identify with the person.

[identification in psychology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identification_(psychology))

Answer (score 1):

I would call it *contagiousness* or *sympathetic reaction*.  Examples:

> I'm very susceptible to the **contagiousness** of someone else's concert nerves.  If I visit a green room, I get nauseous, even if I'm not going to be performing.
>
> When it comes to my sister's panic attacks, I get a strong **sympathetic reaction**.  I'm working on increasing my separation from her emotional level.

Comment: While I don't feel it's quite perfect for the feeling I'm trying to encompass, contagious does come about the closest.  It's not quite sympathy or empathy, it's more like standing next to a fire, while not burning you're feeling it.

Comment: @poeticvampire - There's a term in psychology: if A is in a situation where B would feel X, B may then *project*, meaning B assumes A is feeling what he would feel in that situation, and reacts and responds accordingly. I guess that's different from what you described.  Maybe we could also say *pick up on someone's (specific emotion)*.

Comment: The person who feels nervous and causes the other person to feel nervous -- for no reason -- might *send nervous vibes my way* or *be sending me nervous vibes*.

Answer (score 0):

*Sympathy* consists of the prefix *sym* "alike, equal" and the stem *path-* "feel, suffer". Common usage differs in most English registers for [sympathetic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sympathetic), yet *Sympathy* is defined exactly as asked for

> [sympathy](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sympathy) 1. an affinity, association, or relationship between persons or things wherein whatever affects one similarly affects the other. [...].

The question is, to a degree, not one of language but philosophy and associated fields, including medicine. The name [sympatheic nervous system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sympathetic_nervous_system) "*can be traced to the concept of sympathy, in the sense of "connection between parts", first used medically by Galen*".

Answer (score -1):

Using the idea of the word ‘project’, as aparente001 suggested, gave me the word ‘projection’. I like that word, to name what would otherwise be awkward to name & explain. Projection, in this instance, would make you the ‘receiver’, of what someone else ‘projected’. Thus, primarily taking the ‘focus’ off yourself, making it easier to confide perhaps.